# Print multidimensional array in bash returns only last element

Tags: bash, multidimensional-array

I am doing some exercises about multidimensional arrays in Bash (v.4) and the following is a simple script that create a fixed 6x6 matrix.

Every row is filled with a single line of space-separated integers. The first 'echo' prints the just filled element and it is correct.
Right after, it print the whole matrix with a double for loop, but the result is a 6x6 matrix with only the last element (element with index 5,5).

I tried to print some elements with explicit indexes, but the script don't prints any value.

What's wrong with the following code?

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A VET
idx_max=5

for i in `seq 0 $idx_max`
do
    read string

    IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$string"

    for j in `seq 0 $idx_max`
    do
        VET[i,j]=${array[j]}
        echo -n "$i,$j: ${VET[i,j]} "
    done
    echo
done

echo "========================="

for i in `seq 0 $idx_max`
do
    for j in `seq 0 $idx_max`
    do
        echo -n "$i,$j: ${VET[i,j]} "
    done
    echo
done

echo "3,4: ${VET[3,4]}"
echo "5,1: ${VET[5,1]}"
echo "5,5: ${VET[5,5]}"
```

This is the excution of the script:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
0,0: 1 0,1: 2 0,2: 3 0,3: 4 0,4: 5 0,5: 6
7 8 9 0 1 2
1,0: 7 1,1: 8 1,2: 9 1,3: 0 1,4: 1 1,5: 2
3 4 5 6 7 8
2,0: 3 2,1: 4 2,2: 5 2,3: 6 2,4: 7 2,5: 8
9 0 1 2 3 4
3,0: 9 3,1: 0 3,2: 1 3,3: 2 3,4: 3 3,5: 4
5 6 7 8 9 0
4,0: 5 4,1: 6 4,2: 7 4,3: 8 4,4: 9 4,5: 0
1 2 3 4 5 6
5,0: 1 5,1: 2 5,2: 3 5,3: 4 5,4: 5 5,5: 6
=========================
0,0: 6 0,1: 6 0,2: 6 0,3: 6 0,4: 6 0,5: 6
1,0: 6 1,1: 6 1,2: 6 1,3: 6 1,4: 6 1,5: 6
2,0: 6 2,1: 6 2,2: 6 2,3: 6 2,4: 6 2,5: 6
3,0: 6 3,1: 6 3,2: 6 3,3: 6 3,4: 6 3,5: 6
4,0: 6 4,1: 6 4,2: 6 4,3: 6 4,4: 6 4,5: 6
5,0: 6 5,1: 6 5,2: 6 5,3: 6 5,4: 6 5,5: 6
3,4:
5,1:
5,5:
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out why it don't works.

The command '**declare -A**' is used to create **associative** arrays, and not to create multidimensional arrays.
So, if you want to *simulate* multidimensional array you can create a key that seems a couple of indexes.

I modified the lines 14 and 26 in the following script to get the result; it was

```
VET[i,j]=${array[j]}
```

and now is

```
VET["$i,$j"]=${array[j]}
```

This is the modified script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A VET
idx_max=5

for i in `seq 0 $idx_max`
do
    read string

    IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$string"

    for j in `seq 0 $idx_max`
    do
        VET["$i,$j"]=${array[j]}
    done
    echo
done

echo "========================="

for i in `seq 0 $idx_max`
do
    for j in `seq 0 $idx_max`
    do
        echo -n "$i,$j: ${VET[$i,$j]} "
    done
    echo
done

exit
```